# unable to update the textview to show current available main memory

Tags: android, multithreading, textview

I am trying to write an app which updates the current available main memory every second, I wrote the below code but the app is crashing. without using the thread it is working fine when i added thread the app is crashing

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Thread t;
    ActivityManager activityManager ;
    MemoryInfo mi;
    TextView MainMem_avail;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MainMem_avail=new TextView(this);
    setContentView(MainMem_avail);        
}
public void onResume()
{
    t=new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                while(true)
                {                       
                    mi = new MemoryInfo();
                    activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                          @Override
                          public void run() {
                              MainMem_avail.setText("Available Main memory="+mi.availMem/(1024*1024)+"MB");
                          }
                        });
                    sleep(1000);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("something went wrong");
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
}
public void onPause()
{
    t.destroy();
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant touch the UI from outside the main thread. Instead post a delayed runnable to the main thread handler every second.

An example of how to do this is as follows:

```
final Handler h = new Handler();
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
*Update Text View Here*
h.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};
r.run();
```

To stop it running just call

```
h.removeCallbacks(r);
```

If you make h and r global variables then you can make a start and stop function for them allowing you to toggle its operation by either removing its callbacks or calling run() again

Comment: You can but you arent allowed to block the UI thread with a while(true) loop or using sleep. In order to the runnable to be repeated it you must using something like a TimerTask and when on android you should use a handler instead.

Comment: that's true, I forgot that

Answer (score -1):

I edit, because it was wrong, now it's better

```
final int delay = 0;
final int period = 1000;
final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            mi = new MemoryInfo();
            activityManager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
            MainMem_avail.setText("Available Main memory="+mi.availMem/(1024*1024)+"MB");
        }
        postDelayed(this, period);
    }
};

postDelayed(r, delay);
```

Comment: Surely this will cause the ui to freeze as your calling sleep on the main thread?